# Add content to compass/sass variable and use single output

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass

I want to be able to add and stack css to something like a variable, mixin or placeholder and output it at a given point. I don't know if Sass has some built in behaviour for this. I want to use this for example for including IE specific styling or in use with media queries. I don't want everything to be printed 'inline' but for instance at the bottom of the file or in a separate file. In the code example I tried to explain this a bit more. Don't mention the syntax!

```
.box {
    width:250px;
    @stack mediaquery_var_or_mixin(small) {
        width:100%;
    }
}

.input {
    width:100px;
    @stack mediaquery_var_or_mixin(small) {
        width:100%;
    }
}

echo mediaquery(small);
```

The output would look like this:

```
.box {
    width:250px;
}

.input {
    width:100px;
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .box {
        width:100%;
    }
    .input {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that functionality doesn't exist as a part of Sass.  There has been discussion about it, you can see some of that here:  https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/116#issuecomment-7355117

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter cimmanon mentioned in the comments, this is not a current feature of Sass.

While this feature would make the compressed output simpler, if you serve your files with gzip encoding, the the redundancy created in the compiled css is no longer a major concern.